# Django How to pass str value from link a href to view without modifying urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to ask you for your help with passing a STR value from a href link to my views.py but without modifying urls.py

I am not sure if it possible, but it sounds useful I think, so maybe it is doable?

Right now in order to work I have to use urls.py like this:

```
path('my_notes/', views.my_notes, {'category': 'Python'}, name='my_notes'),
```

But I would like to go completely "DRY" and do something like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'my_notes' %}" category="Python">Python</a>
```

And in views.py:

```
def my_notes(request):
    category = request.GET['category']
    notes = Note.objects.filter(category__category=category, sub_category__sub_category="Notes")
    snippets = Note.objects.filter(category__category=category, sub_category__sub_category="Code_Snippets")
    context = {
        'notes': notes,
        'snippets': snippets,
        'category': category
    }
    return render(request, 'my_notes.html', context)
```

But with this solution i get "MultiValueDictKeyError". I googled it and I tried to convert it to dict, try to add additional "false" arguments but I can't get it to work. I am not even sure if it's right approach?

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'my_notes' %}?category=Python">Python</a>

Comment: Wow, it's working! Thank you very much. I would like to select this as answer but it's in the comments so I am unable to do this. Can you also please tell me what is it called, or what exactly happened so I can google and research it?

Comment: please go through http protocol.